# Grant an automatic select to a all tables / PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a production database, where the user can create a set of tables that inherits a master table X. The matter is when i want to apply an automatic grant for all the tables;

Naturally with this command : `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO read_only ;` this will only be applied to tables that have already been created.

The aim, is to applied the command for all the newest tables.

> NB : I already tried to make a trigger on tables pg_class,
>   pg_namespace but it's impossible and it's the same for the pg_tables
>   view;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the default grants for newly created objects with the [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) command, e.g.:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
FOR USER creator_role IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO read_only;
```

As an aside, while you can't install triggers on the system catalogs, you can achieve the same thing (in Postgres 9.3+) with [event triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/event-trigger-definition.html), which fire on any `CREATE`/`DROP`/`ALTER` statement.

Comment: I solved the problem with the following command : `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO read_only;`